# How to resolve circular dependency between beans in Spring IoC?

Tags: java, spring

Suppose I have a bean which depends on another bean, and another bean depends on first bean.

```
Bean#1 -> Bean#2 -> Bean#1
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is from [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#d0e2299)

> You can generally trust Spring to do the right thing. It detects
>   configuration problems, such as references to non-existent beans and
>   circular dependencies, at container load-time. Spring sets properties
>   and resolves dependencies as late as possible, when the bean is
>   actually created.

So it instantiates both beans and injects them onto each other.

### EDIT

In your case `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException` mostly arose due to constructor injection. If that is the case mostly using setter injection instead of constructor injection will solve the issue. Constructor injection typically gives rise to the chicken-egg problem!

Comment: I ran into a problem when I use one version of Spring which use dependencies with old dependencies. And Spring cannot resolve it.

Answer (score 6):

You can get around by using setter injection. However, generally this is a bad idea since the code will be harder to maintain and test. I suggest that you refactor your code to only have unidirectional dependencies, e.g.

```
BeanA -> BeanB
```

Another way of solving this is to pull out the common behavior in a third bean class, and then let the two initial classes depend on it, e.g.

```
BeanA -> BeanC
BeanB -> BeanC
```